# Cannot add service to apereo cas-overlay-template project. Application Not Authorized to Use CAS

Tags: cas, apereo

I am trying to add a service to cas-overlay-template project that I am deploying locally.
My service json looks like this

```
{
  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId" : "^(http?|imaps?)://.*",
  "name" : "HTTPSandIMAPS",
  "id" : 8081,
  "description" : "This service definition authorizes all application urls that support HTTPS and IMAPS protocols.",
  "evaluationOrder" : 1,
  "logoutType" : "BACK_CHANNEL",
  "logoutUrl" : "http://localhost:8081/logout",
}
```

and I have saved it in the /etc/cas/services folder.
I still get the message **'Application Not Authorized to Use CAS'**.
The url that I use to login to cas is **https://localhost:8443/cas/login?service=http://localhost:8081/cas/login**

Comment: are you sure it is looking in /etc/cas/services? Do you see this actually print in your logs? Try explicitly setting your services directory in cas.properties  cas.serviceRegistry.json.location: file:C:/etc/cas/services